# How to Show the application on taskbar?

Tags: c#

i developed a window application using c# language and created a setup for that. when i minimize the window it will be in systemtray.Now i need when i minimize it should be in both system tray and taskbar how it is possible help me thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**ShowInTaskBar**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx)

EDIT : If you are hiding the form when it is minimized, don't hide it.

Comment: Thank you dude it is working ya i hide it now used 
 WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; it iswoking fine thank you
Mr. Mahin

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to not do anything.  You form should have a Systray component on it, that adds the item to the system tray, and you don't need to do anything with the minimise/showintaskbar behaviour.

You may or may not wish to show/hide the systray icon on minimise/restore, but I wouldn't recommend that because it would be weird behaviour, unless you're also hiding from the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

Take the properties for the windows form in your windows application [not in your setup project].

There you can set the

**ShowInTaskBar** property to **True**

which determines whether the form appears in the task bar or not.